# How to show text input on start when text is too long but automatically focus on end when tap in android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am having issue on text input on android when the text is too long. I want to replicate the behaviour in iOS that is showing the start and when tap cursor automatically set to end of text.

[image]

I tried this code it works for showing the start text but when I tap the text input and type something the cursor retains to index 0.

```
selection={{start:0}}
```